# datatype promotion in c

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
signed char a= 0x80;
unsigned char b= 0x01;


void main (void)
{
    if(b*a>1)
        printf("promoted\n");
    else if (b*a<1)
        printf("why doesnt promotion work?");

    while(1);
}
```

I expected "promoted' to be printed. But it doesnt. Why?
If I can the datatypes to signed and unsigned int, and have a as a negative number, eg, 0x80000000 and b as a positive number, 0x01, "promoted" gets printed as expected.

PLZ HELP me understand what the problem is!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've just been caught by the messy type-promotion rules of C.

In C, intermediates of integral type smaller than `int` are automatically promoted to `int`.

So you have:

```
0x80 * 0x01 = -128 * 1
```

`0x80` gets signed extended to type `int`:

```
0xffffff80 * 0x00000001 = -128 * 1 = -128
```

So the result is `-128` and thus is less than `1`.

---

When you use type `int` and `unsigned int`, both operands get promoted to `unsigned int`. `0x80000000 * 0x01 = 0x80000000` as an unsigned integer is bigger than `1`.

---

So here's the side-by-side comparison of the type promotion that's taking place:

```
(signed char) * (unsigned char) -> int
(signed int ) * (unsigned int ) -> unsigned int

(signed char)0x80       * (unsigned char)0x01 -> (int)         0xffffff80
(signed int )0x80000000 * (unsigned int )0x01 -> (unsigned int)0x80000000

(int)         0xffffff80 is negative   ->   prints "why doesnt promotion work?"
(unsigned int)0x80000000 is positive   ->   prints "promoted"
```

[Here's a reference to the type-promotion rules of C.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)

Comment: @Mystical I dont understand your answer. Even if it gets signed extended to type int, which I dont think it does, but assuming it does, why isnt it being promoted to unsigned int, and product being a +ve number?

Comment: +1 - This answer is much better/more relevant than mine by a long mile (so I deleted it)

Comment: @Dom045 Because the specification says so. Both `signed char` and `unsigned char` are lower types than `int`. So they will both be promoted to `int`. In the `signed int` vs. `unsigned int` case, the standard dictates that they both be converted to `unsigned int`. The rules can be found here: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules

Comment: @Mystical: Ok, I didnt know about chars being promoted to ints. My bad. But help me understand this please. if " In the signed int vs. unsigned int case, the standard dictates that they both be converted to unsigned int." then shouldnt the product be unsigned, and hence positive? I am just not really clear about promotion.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In the `signed int` vs. `unsigned int` case, the result is unsigned and is thus positive. I'll expand my answer in a bit to make this more clear.

Comment: @Mystical: Bottom line, if there is an arithmetic operation between unsigned char and signed char, both get promoted to an INT and not an UNSIGNED INT, correct?

Comment: @Dom045 Yes, that's correct. To be pedantic, it might be different if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`. I'm not sure what happens in this case, but there are very few environments where `char` is the same size as `int` so I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `printf("promoted\n");` never runs
is because `b*a` is always == `-128`, which is less than `1`

```
a       b       
0x80 * 0x01 = -128 * 1
```